# Using the value of one value in another?

Tags: javascript, object

So excuse me if my question isn't 100% clear, hopefully you'll understand what I mean.

I want to be able to do something like this in JS, and I'm wondering if it's possible:

```
export const type = {
    link: 'dark-blue',
    text: `${link} f2` // using the value of the first in the second
}
```

This works:

```
const link = 'dark-blue'

export const type = {
    text: link + ' f2'
}
```

But the problem with this, is that I have to separate my link variable outside of the object.

Any ideas?

Comment: The object doesn't exist until after the object literal is evaluated, so you can't set one property to the value of another property. You could change `text` to be a getter method that returns a value making use of the `link` property. Also, your second block produces an object with only one property - do you not want it to have a `link` property?

Comment: you can't do the first thing in js

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can mutate an object after you exported it:

```
export const type = {
  link: 'dark-blue'
}
type.text = `${type.link} f2`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The singleton model may work, however you would have to do `type.text()`

```
    const type = {
      link: 'red',
      text: function() {
        return `${this.link} f2`
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to do is to reference the `link` variable inside type object, but you can't do this because the object is not created yet.

```
export const type = {
    link: 'dark-blue',
    text: `${link} f2` // using the value of the first in the second
}
```

So the better way is:

```
const type = {
    link: 'dark-blue'
};

type.text = `${type.link} f2`;

export type;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use block scope to define `link` and `text` then set the properties to `type`

```js
let type;
{
  const link = "dark-blue", text = `${link} f2`;
  type = {link, text};
}

console.log(type)
```